# php - how to display a web page to clients who are blocked from accessing a URL with PHP or some other method?

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I need your help. 
I have a website... lets call it `website A`, and I was trying to use ajax to get content from `website B` (they are not on the same server). The reason is becuase in my country, there is a internet provider that if you are using this provider, you can't connect to `website B`.  However, everyone can connect to `website A`. So, there are some clients who can't get the content from `website B`.

My idea was: when you connect to `website A`, an ajax request is made to `website B` to get the contents.  The problem is that `ajax`  still requires that the person making the request to `website A`  has to be able to access `website B`.

Is there a way that visitors to `website A`  can use the internet connection that `website A` is connected through to fetch the content from `website B` and then display it directly via `website A`?

Here is what I attempted to do, which did not work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://websiteB.com?a=information&id=<?=$id?>',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
        },
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#content').html(data);
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is unfortunately off-topic. You need to include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: I think problem in Ajax Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. while you access content from b to a then did you put crossDomain:true, in ajax request

Comment: @Panda is right....@KaZat you should follow stack overflow document to ask understandable and effective question.

Comment: You can setup a location on website A to act as a reverse proxy for site B if you have access to the server configuration for site A -- ajax isnt possible unless you set the headers for Site B and Site A properly

Comment: @mike510a yes I think it is proxy but I don't have much experience with it. is it easy to setup? Can I use a proxy from where?

Comment: You'll have to have access to the server configuration file for website A - can you tell us a little more about website A and what type of host it is (self-hosted, paid-hosting, free, other) and the type of httpd that is running (nginx, apache, lighttpd, etc)?

Comment: or if website A allows `url_fopen()`   then you can do it programmatically with PHP

Comment: @mike510a Iam using self-hosted with apache :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In order to retrieve content from a site which blocks connections from the client who wishes to access the content, but the server which the client is connecting to is not blocked, you can simple fetch the content of `website B` using PHP from the `server` (`website A`)  and then print it to the screen for the client.

This will not allow them to follow links or anything else, but you can retrieve the content of a single page this way.

If you wish to mirror the entire site, you can use an apache reverse proxy (see part 2)

It is also important to note that you need to make sure the setting  `allow_url_fopen()`  is set to `true` in the `php.ini`  file for `website A`

---

On `websiteA`  in the file `get_website_b.php`

```html
<?php 
 $websiteBcontent = file_get_contents( 'http://www.websiteB.com/'); 
 print_r($websiteBcontent); 
?>
```

---

**Part 2**

To mirror an entire domain  such as `website B`  onto `website A`,  you can add a virtualhost entry into your apache `httpd.conf` file

```
  <VirtualHost www.websiteA.com:*>
      ProxyPreserveHost On 
      ProxyPass / http://www.websiteB.com/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://www.websiteB.com/
      ServerName websiteA.com
  </VirtualHost>
```

You must also make sure that you have the `mod_proxy` module loaded which can be loaded using the `loadModule` directive.

(see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule)

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my life. I tested it by edit site B in hosts file in system32. So, I can't connect to B but from A the content still show up.

Comment: Depending on how `site B` has their HTML content linked, it may or may not be possible to follow links using the `reverse proxy method`  (only if site B uses relative URLs and not absolute ones), and the `get_file_contents()` method will not allow for navigation to other pages or external resources like scripts, images, etc.. to load..  You would need to do some tricky PHP coding to remove the `https://www.websiteA.com`  part from all external URLS with php's `str_replace()`  function